# Check whether a number is in a given range: fails to print message as instructed

Tags: python

I am trying to write a program in Python to check whether a number is in a given range and I want it to print a message when it's not. However, the following code I have come up with fails to print such a message (it works for the first two conditions, but not the third). I'd appreciate if someone could point out if there is a mistake in my code and also if there is a more efficient way to write it.

```
def range(a,b,n):
    if b > a:
        if(n>=a) and (n<=b):
            print(n,"is within the range",a,"-",b)
    elif b < a:
        if(n>=b) and (n<=a):
            print(n,"is within the range",a,"-",b)
    else:
        if (n>a,b) or (n<a,b):
            print(n, "is not within the range", a,"-",b)
```

When I test the code with

```
range(2,8,300)
```

it prints nothing when it should print `300 is not within the range 2 - 8`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a interval comparison:

```
def range(a,b,n):
    if a <= n <= a:
            print(n,"is within the range",a,"-",b)
    else:
            print(n, "is not within the range", a,"-",b)


range(2,8,300)
```

OUTPUT:

```
300 is not within the range 2 - 8
```

OR alternatively:

```
   def check_range(a,b,n):    
   isRange = range(min(a,b),max(a,b))
   if n in isRange:
       print(n, "is within the range", a, "-", b)
   else:
       print(n, "is not within the range", a, "-", b)


check_range(5,2,4)
```

OUTPUT:

```
4 is within the range 5 - 2
```

> PS. I would not encourage using the Python built-in function `range()`
>   as your custom function name.

[pyFiddle](https://pyfiddle.io/fiddle/0f66581e-aeb6-4f8e-b71f-e38c262931b9/?m=Saved%20fiddle)

Comment: Thank you. What if a > b, in which case n can still be within the range, but a <=n <= b would not be true?

Comment: @Madrid_datalady I've edited to add that case in the alternative method. cheers

Comment: Thanks again. I ran the `def check_range` option and although it makes perfect sense,  when I test it on check_range(5,2,4), I get a `TypeError: range() missing 1 required positional argument: 'n'`

Comment: @Madrid_datalady Did you run the exact code? I've tested with `check_range(5,2,4)` and it returns `4 is within the range 5 - 2` just like it should.

Comment: @Madrid_datalady I've added a pyFiddle to test it online.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187996/discussion-between-madrid-datalady-and-user5173426).

Comment: @Madrid_datalady You may accept the answer if it helped, Thank you!

Comment: I already upvoted your answer but how do I "accept" it? I don´t see an option to do that.

Comment: @Madrid_datalady you may click on the `tick mark` shown beside the answer: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 2):

```
def range(a,b,n):
    if a < b:
        if n >= a:
            if n <= b:
                print(n,"is within the range",a,"-",b)
            else:
                print(n, "is not within the range", a,"-",b)    
        else:
            print(n, "is not within the range", a,"-",b)                
    if a > b:
        if n <= a:
            if n >= b:
                print(n,"is within the range",a,"-",b)
            else: 
                print(n, "is not within the range", a,"-",b)
        else:
            print(n, "is not within the range", a,"-",b)
```

This should work.

EDIT: Modified the code. This will also test the cases involving negative numbers and zero.

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful! (I upvoted you but just wanted to say thanks anyway)

Answer (score 1):

`if 8 > 2:` is true, so it goes inside and the nested `if 300>=2 and 8<=300` condition 
fails and exits. So, it never goes to `else` loop.

Also, `if (n>a,b) or (n<a,b)` this always returns `True`. Since **`("anything..")`** becomes tuple and it's always True.

This works fine.

```
def fun(x,y,z):
    x , y = min(x,y), max(x,y)
    if z >= x and z <= y:
         print(z," is within the range",x,"-",y)
    else:
         print(, "is not within the range", x,"-",y)
```

Comment: Right... yes, it goes inside the first nested loop, but then it evaluates if 300>=2 and 300<=8, which is obviously not true. In any case, how do I fix the code so that it prints a message when n is outside the range, without going into any of the first two nested loops?

Comment: Thanks! I tried the fun(x,y,z) function with fun(25,11,17) and it prints: 17 is not within the range 25 - 25

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
def range(a, b, n):
    if a <= n <= b:
        print(n, "is within the range", a, "-", b)
    else:
        print(n, "is not within the range", a, "-", b)
```

**Update:**

```
def range(a, b, n):
    if a > b:
        if a>=n and b<=n:
            print(n, "is within the range", a, "-", b)
        else:
            print(n, "is not within the range", a, "-", b)
    else:
        if a <= n <= b:
            print(n, "is within the range", a, "-", b)
        else:
            print(n, "is not within the range", a, "-", b)
```

Then

```
>>> range(2, 8, 300)
300 is not within the range 2 - 8
>>> range(2, 8, 5)
5 is within the range 2 - 8
```

Comment: range(400,8,380) check this condition

Comment: Thank you. What if a > b, in which case n can still be within the range, but a <=n <= b would not be true?

Comment: I consider normal use case. A special case is not specified in the question. I will try the special case if I can,